# How do I use the performance api to measure how long to complete all display updates after a state change in react

Tags: reactjs

I know to use the mark and measure but not sure how/where to place it. i.e. to know the rendering is completely done to end the duration.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fire it when e.g. clicking on a button, it should be in an effect hook, like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    performance.mark('performanceStart');

    // Do you state updates here etc.

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      performance.mark('performanceEnd');
      performance.measure('performance', 'performanceStart', 'performanceEnd');
      const measure = performance.getEntriesByName('performance')[0];
      console.log(measure.duration);
    });
  }, []);
```